# Order of growth for algorithms: $\log(n)^{4}$or $\log(n)^{4}$ vs $5\sqrt(n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I am not sure how to compare behaviour of $\log^4n$ or $\log^2n$ to $5\sqrt n $ for growth. Can someone help me compare it with an explanation?

Comment: Do you understand how to compare, say, $n^2$ with $e^{n/2}$? The situation is the same here after making a substitution.

Comment: Is it $\ln(n^4)$ or $(\ln(n))^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking the logarithm.
$$\log(\log^4 n) =4\log \log n$$
$$\log 5\sqrt n=\frac12\log n+\log 5$$
If you are comfortable with the fact that $\log x$ is asymptotically smaller than $ax$ for any $a>0$, it is clear which is larger.